# Using 'requests_html' with 'FastAPI'

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, fastapi, python-requests-html

I'm trying to use the `requests_html` library with js rendering along with `FastAPI`:

script.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from requests_html import HTMLSession

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def func():
    with HTMLSession() as session:
        r = session.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
        r.html.render()
        return r.text
```

when running using `uvicorn script:app --reload` and accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
,I get the following error:

```
...
 r.html.render()
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 727, in browser
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

Any idea how can I make them work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AsyncHTMLSession in Uvicorn

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def func():
    asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
    r = await asession.get('https://stackoverflow.org/')

    await r.html.arender()

    return r.text
```

Comment: Works great, thank u.
I also get this warning on the 1st request
```
.\scratch.py:13: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'HTML.arender' was never awaited
  r.html.arender()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
``` is that an issue?

Comment: please replace "r.html.arender()" to "await r.html.arender()"